# Referencing AppDelegate Methods - iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an AppDelegate which has 3 views. I add all three

```
[window addSubview:gameViewController.view];
[window addSubview:viewSettings.view];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the app delegate, i have some methodes for swapping views by calling

```
[window bringSubviewToFront:gameViewController.view];
```

When i am inside viewController, I use

```
pinkAppDelegate *appDelegate=  (pinkAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate switchToSettings];
```

to switch my subviews...so far so good.

BUT, when I'm in my viewSetting UIViewController, and do the same appDelegate call, it chocks, like it doesn't understand how to call the appDelegate method.

I've got all my views hooked in my mainwindow xib, but can't figure out why i can't traverse the methods in the main appdelegate

Comment: Do you maen that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` fails? or that you can't send it a `switchToSettings` message? Is this runtime or compile time?

Comment: run time...i can't send the message.

i CAN from one view..but not from another...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Inside viewController, you're setting up a local variable called appDelegate that points at your app delegate. That's what this line does:

```
pinkAppDelegate *appDelegate= (pinkAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

This variable is local to viewController, so you can't use it in the settings view controller. You need to set up another variable there.

Alternatively, use this nice #define throughout your app. (You'll need to put it in a .h header file that you include in every file in your project.)

```
#define myAppDelegate (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Then you can do the following anywhere:

```
[myAppDelegate doSomething];
```

Comment: Why not call directly?:

[[[UIApplication sharedApplicaion delegate] doSomething]

Comment: Apart from the fact that UIApplication will not have those custom methods anyway ...

Comment: @stefanB all that [[UIApplication delegate shared blah blah is ugly and this solution helps avoif errors like jalo has.

Comment: What custom methods? I'm just suggesting a #define to make the app delegate call prettier and minimise typing errors.

Comment: The #define version does not seem to work for me.
I get warning "UIApplication may not respond to +sharedApplication" kind of error, and is not working after launch... 
any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

For reference there is still a typo in the above, also I have another addition which helps avoid warnings of having to cast every time. if you use:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
#define myAppDelegate (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

I put the above in a constants.h and then can use

```
[myAppDelegate doSomething];
```

anywhere I import constants.h

Answer (score 1):

Jane's answer had a typo in it.

Use the following line in a header file (e.g. defines.h) that you import in every class:

```
#define myAppDelegate [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

You could also use the line in a prefix header file - this is an easy way of getting access to this everywhere.

then in any method you can use any of the following:

```
[myAppDelegate doSomething]; 
 myAppDelegate.property=value;
 myAppDelegate.childClassOfMyAppDelegate.property=value;
[myAppDelegate.ChildOfMyAppDelegate doSomething];
```